# Passing data from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I have a silly question :
In my controller I set :

```
ViewBag.totalCount = 20
```

In the view I want to call:

```
@Html.Pager(8, 1, @ViewBag.totalCount);
```

but I think that ViewBag is not recognized as the whole method call is underlined in VS. It has to be something simple. How can I so it please ? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried removing the `@` on Viewbag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just need

```
@Html.Pager(8, 1, (int)ViewBag.totalCount)
```

assuming it's an `int` (you need to cast as it will be `dynamic`). No `@` in front of ViewBag (since you're already in code) and, if pager returns non-void, you can omit the trailing `;`

Answer (score 0):

It should be `ViewBag.totalCount`, not `@ViewBag.totalCount`.