# Is there a way to access a custom helper from a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view, controller

I am building this MVC3 Razor ASP.NET application in which I am using a custom WebViewPage that inherits from that. So all my views use my custom WebViewPage:

```
public class MyCustomWebViewPage : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
{
    public CustomHelper MyHelper { get; private set; }
         :
}
```

And then in the web.config located in the Views folder I indicated that MyCustomViewPage is my default base page.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="Namespace.MyCustomWebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
             :
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

So far so good, on the View's .cshtml pages I can access my custom helper from the razor markup:

```
@MyHelper.SomeMethod()
```

Now, there is something I need to do conditionally on the helper. I tried setting the helper's property in the @{} startup section of the CSHTML but that is too late for it to be taken into account.

So, I am thinking of doing it either on the invoked Action method, or by overriding the OnActionExecuting() method.

The problem I have is that in the controller I have not found out a way to access my custom helper such as:

```
public class AnyController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index() {
        MyHelper.SomeProperty = true;
    }
}
```

To explain it a bit more, the concept is that in an action (the action code in the controller) I want to set a property in the custom helper that would enable certain functionality. This way this is not rendered on views that do not need it. It is different from the concept of @section in which the content is defined in the view, rather it says "I want this feature added to the layout" and the layout would output some predefined markup that would enable that feature AND that in several places of the view there might be "nuggets" that require that "feature support markup or script". If I use a section, then that "common" script would appear multiple times which is not what I need.

Having said that, How can I access a (custom) helper defined in the base view page from within a controller?

Answer (score 2):

Consider passing the information through model instead as it is more in-line with MVC. You can either use strongly typed Model or weakly typed ViewBag (sample - [Passing data from controller to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272697/passing-data-from-controller-to-view)).

Controller is not expected to know what exact page will be used to render a view. It just says something "find a view with this name and render this data (model)". There could be different views matching the same name depending on different conditions, so normally you don't have a way to set properties of view object from controller.

Edit: Why it is technically very hard:

Lifetime of an action method call (`ActionResult Index(){...}`) does not intersect with lifetime of the page (WebViewPage object). WebViewPage object created after action is completed execution. So if you really interested in pushing data from action directly into a view object (not through built in mechanisms) you will need to figure out how to pass some chunk of code (likely in form of delegate) to view creation code.

Comment: The information I am trying to access is totally independent of the model. As I indicated it is a helper that allows me to do certain things. For example some Google AdSense helper methods that I may or may not want to use in a view. For that reason I want to be able to access the custom webviewpage to tell it whether to render something or not. It is also not the section functionality.

Comment: I've added comments why it would be very hard... Consider using existing ways instead...

Comment: Eh, I don't want to push stuff after the view is rendered. I want, @Alexei-levenkov prior to the view being rendered, set an attribute/property so that the master layout of the view renders some data (includes a common script). After that is done I don't need update anything, the view is rendered as I want it.

Comment: To my knowledge WebViewPage object is created **after** action method returns - which is why it is hard to set any property on it from Controller's code. You master view can look at ViewBag and do something - may work for you...